# Escape = false for field level error messages

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation-rule

So I have a validation rule, which has a **double quote(")** in its error message. The location of the error message is at field level.

Suppose for example, the error message is:

> You need to enter a valid "Account Name"

This message gets displayed as:

> You need to enter a valid `&quot;Account Name&quot;`

I am aware that, keeping `escape= false` in `pagemessages` would display the double quote instead of `&quot;` in `visualforce` page.

The problem I am facing is on the field level error messages. Is there anything to display the field level messages with proper double quotes(without escaping)?

Comment: Is this in a visualforce page where you have inputField?

Comment: yes its in VF page

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IZhOQAW). You might need to use single quotes or eliminate the quotes altogether. Alternatively, use `pagemessages` with `escape=false` as you already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information. Was thinking of trying this through `javaScript` as the last resort, not sure how good practice is that.

Comment: It's definitely an option. If the aim is to provide a better user experience, then go for it. I'd weigh the value vs the effort first though